# how can I clear data when device back button is pressed?

Tags: android

I have this kind of code but it seems not to work

```
public static class DeleteDir {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        deleteDirectory(new File(args[0]));
    }

    static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        if (path.exists()) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                } else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return (path.delete());
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TeacherSide.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't seem to work"? What happens and what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using the [`onKeyDown`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) method, which is probably not the best method to use for the back button, your code should work. I tested your code and it did work for me. The problem may lie in *the code you run* when the back button is pressed, not with whether or not the code actually runs.

```java
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeacherSide.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        // you don't need to call finish(); because 
        // return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); does that for you

        // clear your SharedPreferences
        getSharedPreferences("preferenceName",0).edit().clear().commit();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

---

Here's another way:

Use Android's [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method:

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed(); // this can go before or after your stuff below
    // do your stuff when the back button is pressed
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeacherSide.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    // super.onBackPressed(); calls finish(); for you

    // clear your SharedPreferences
    getSharedPreferences("preferenceName",0).edit().clear().commit();
}
```

Comment: @kyo in what ways is it not working? It's starting the activity just fine for me.

Comment: I have scores to be recorded in the last activity and I want to clear all the scores just like clearing it in the Settings-->Application-->Manage Application-->myApps-->Clear Data

Comment: yes mike . I want to clear my sharedPreferences when I pressed the device back button

Comment: I mean , I really want to clear all the data so that the recorded scores will be deleted and record again when I start my app all over again.

Comment: I recorded it as sharedPreference

Comment: I have here 5 classes to be pasted . Here's the link mike http://pastie.org/8599558 .

Comment: I don't know why but when I try to call the getScore() it's not accurate . If I'm going to make all the answers "correct" for the first try , it seems to be okey because the "congratulations" will appear but when I try it again and make all the answers "incorrect" it should be "failed" but the "congratulations" is still appearing .

Comment: I have that MainActivity.class here but I didn't paste it in pastie.org . I only paste the class that I'm confused with .

Comment: @kyo I'm not sure how getting your SharedPreferences work. Let's try doing this my way. Go to this pastie and read what I have to say on getting and setting your SharedPreferences: http://pastie.org/8599607 Please tell me if those instructions fix your problem so that I can update my answer.

Comment: mike . where do you want me to put those methods ? in which class ? in all the class ?

Comment: @kyo let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44484/discussion-between-mike-yaworski-and-kyo)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PreviousActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

And if this last activity or there is any PreviousActivity , then put this code before `setContentView()`

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}           
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

In this way you can clear data.

Answer (score 3):

After 2.0 we have `onBackPressed()` to handle Back button.

You can override `onBackPressed()` function and implement your logic

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()// called when the Back button is pressed
{
// do stuff
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: and dont forget to call `super.onBackPressed()` at the end

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using `onBackPressed()` like other people say unless you creating something below API 5 then go for `onKeyDown()`.

If you really want to use the onKeyDown try this code and check inside log if it work then put necessary code inside

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       Log.i("back press", "back");
       return true;
   } else {
       Log.i("else back ", "else back");
   }
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Comment: I'm using API above 8